# WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 - chpasswd.sh not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have installed WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS. After replacing the default wso2carbon keystore I need to reset the admin password using the utility chpasswd.sh. This is where I run into problems, see below.

```
root@test:~/wso2is-5.0.0/bin# ./chpasswd.sh --db-url "jdbc:h2:/root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB"
Buildfile: /root/wso2is-5.0.0/bin/build.xml

setup:
     [copy] Copying 41 files to /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/lib
    [mkdir] Created dir: /root/wso2is-5.0.0/tmp/setup
    [unzip] Expanding: /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.stub_4.2.0.jar into /root/wso2is-5.0.0/tmp/setup
    [unzip] Expanding: /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt.ui_4.2.0.jar into /root/wso2is-5.0.0/tmp/setup
    [unzip] Expanding: /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt_4.2.5.jar into /root/wso2is-5.0.0/tmp/setup
   [delete] Deleting directory /root/wso2is-5.0.0/tmp/setup
    [unzip] Expanding: /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/components/plugins/h2-database-engine_1.2.140.wso2v3.jar into /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/lib
    [unzip] Expanding: /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.utils_4.2.0.jar into /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/lib
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/lib
     [move] Moving 172 files to /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/lib
   [delete] Deleting directory /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/lib/META-INF
   [delete] Deleting directory /root/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/lib/org

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
Username: admin
New password:

Re-enter new password:

[2014-06-07 22:56:16,110] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager} -  Using sql : UPDATE UM_USER SET UM_USER_PASSWORD= ?, UM_SALT_VALUE=?, UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE=?, UM_CHANGED_TIME=? WHERE UM_USER_NAME= ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=?
Error updating credentials for user admin : org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Parameter "#6" is not set; SQL statement:
UPDATE UM_USER SET UM_USER_PASSWORD= ?, UM_SALT_VALUE=?, UM_REQUIRE_CHANGE=?, UM_CHANGED_TIME=? WHERE UM_USER_NAME= ? AND UM_TENANT_ID=? [90012-140]
root@test:~/wso2is-5.0.0/bin#
```

It looks like there is a bug in the script. Anyone who knows how to solve this?

Comment: I get the same error. Looks like there is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. `chpasswd.sh` script file is used to change the password of users, when user store is a JBDC based user store. It means, `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager` must be enabled in your `user-mgt.xml` file.  All `Carbon` based products are shipped with enabling JDBC user store except `Identity Server`.  WSO2 `Identity Server` uses a LDAP server as its default user store. It starts an embedded ApacheDS LDAP server internally and connects to that LDAP server. Therefore you can not use `chpasswd.sh` script file to change the password `Identity Server` unless it has been connected to JDBC user store. If you wish to change the `admin` password,  You need to login to LDAP server and do it. There are several ways, you can do it. You can connect to embedded LDAP using any available LDAP browser (ex- Directory studio) and change the `admin` password using it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Asela! I was misled by some other information I had found and your response made me leave the dead end I was going into. The real problem was actually connected to the replacement of the keystore and configuration mistake from my side.